# Three.js - Rotate 3D model around real axes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js, 3d

I have centered an imported GLTF 3D Model around the axes:

[image]

However, when I rotate it using

```js
scene.rotation.y += 0.01
```

It rotates around a completely different set of axes:
[See here for gif](https://media2.giphy.com/media/HqysM3k0FUd7Vl3tNK/giphy.gif?cid=790b7611b7ad656bc6be08f0985f891e17e48083a368e174&rid=giphy.gif&ct=g).

Here is my code (it is inside a react `App.UseEffect`):

```js
const test = new SceneInit('myThreeJsCanvas');
test.initialize(); //seperate file for setting up camera and lighting etc
test.animate();

let loadedModel;
const glftLoader = new GLTFLoader();
glftLoader.load('./assets/planet/scene.gltf', (gltfScene) => {
   loadedModel = gltfScene;

   const center = new THREE.Vector3();
   center.z = -5
   gltfScene.scene.position.sub(center); //centering
   gltfScene.scene.scale.set(0.01, 0.01, 0.01);
   test.scene.add(gltfScene.scene);
});

const animate = () => {
  if (loadedModel) {
     //loadedModel.scene.rotation.x += 0.01;
     loadedModel.scene.rotation.y += 0.01;
     //loadedModel.scene.rotation.z += 0.01;
   }
   requestAnimationFrame(animate);
};
animate();
```

What am I doing wrong here? I have followed multiple other posts and methods, most including the now deprecated `geometry` all to no avail.

Comment: My crystal ball says that the matrix order is `R * T * S * x` instead of `T * R * S * x`.

Comment: What happens when you `loadedModel.scene.rotation.x += 0.01` or `loadedModel.scene.rotation.z += 0.01`?

Comment: @newQOpenGLWidget the exact same occurs, it all rotated around some other axes

Comment: Try removing `gltfScene.scene.position.sub(center);`.

Comment: Unfortunately not, it still rotates around its circumference not its center

Comment: set the position of the planet to (0, 0, 0)? Or is it already at the origin?

Comment: Nope, it sticks it to the edge of the axis. I've read about putting a bounding box around the model and rotating the box, but I haven't the slightest idea how to do this.

Comment: I think the model is off-center - that would explain the rotation around the circumference.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247488/discussion-between-meropis-and-new-qopenglwidget).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was in fact nothing to do with my code. It was to do with the model's own origin set in the `gltf` file. To fix, I looked into the file with a text editor and changed the transformation matrix to be centered correctly. After this it rotated perfectly.